Postgresql. Create output like JSON
I have table like next



Name




tblname_01


tblname_02


tblname_03



CREATE TABLE test (
name varchar(128)
);

INSERT INTO test
VALUES
('tblname_01'),
('tblname_02'),
('tblname_03');

SELECT * FROM test;

I would like to get next output:
    {
      "rule-type": "selection",
      "rule-id": "1001",
      "rule-name": "1001",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "tblname_01"
      },
      "rule-action": "include",
      "filters": []
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "selection",
      "rule-id": "1002",
      "rule-name": "1002",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "tblname_02"
      },
      "rule-action": "include",
      "filters": []
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "selection",
      "rule-id": "1003",
      "rule-name": "1003",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "tblname_03"
      },
      "rule-action": "include",
      "filters": []
    }

Actually, I need to create JSON-file from more then 100 names of tables. But, first tried to create JSON-files from three names of tables, but I didn't.

Are you sure about this structure? Looks like it should be an array. Check the different functions how to create objects: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING

Where does all this data in the JSON come from, it's not in your table? Please give a [mcve].

Do you have to do this purely in Postgres? If not, a simple program would query the table, loop through the table names, and insert the names into a template.

For the purposes of constructing a numerical sequence of rules, you can use generate_series and join the original table back on to it:
select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('rule-type', 'selection',
    'rule-id', (1000+n)::text,
    'rule-name', (1000+n)::text,
    'object-locator', jsonb_build_object('schema-name', '%', 'table-name', t1.name),
    'rule-action', 'include',
    'filters', jsonb_build_array()
)) 
from generate_series(1, (select count(*) from test)) n
join (select row_number() over (order by t.name) r, t.* from test t) t1
on t1.r = n

See fiddle.

Thanks for that.
The only one, in your code objects sort by alphabets. How to avoid that and left my sort of order.

@Kvv order of appearance of pairs key-value in a JSON object is trivial, and for that reason it cannot be established. What matters here are levels of the JSON tree.

Based on your data you could do something like this
select
jsonb_agg( 
    jsonb_build_object( 
        'rule-type', 'selection', 
        'rule-id', split_part(name,'_',2)::int+1000,
        'rule-name', split_part(name,'_',2)::int+1000,
        'object-locator', 
            jsonb_build_object(
                'schema-name', '%', 
                'table-name', name
            ),
        'rule-action', 'include',
        'filters', array[]::text[]
    )
)
from test; 

Fiddle to test
